# How to write global converter to convert id (primary key) to entity in spring-data-rest

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am starting with spring-data-rest application. I wrote a search method to query by its associated object. But when expose in spring-data-rest API I want to pass associated objectId instead of object.

```
List<Order> findByCustomer(@Param("customerId") Customer customer);
```

I am expecting the rest resource to expose as follows

```
http://localhost:8080/orders/search/findByCustomer?customerId=1
```

But it expecting me to pass customer object as a query param. To avoid this propblem temporarily I wrote custom query on search method as follows

```
@Query(" from Order o where o.customer.id `= ?")
List<Order> findByCustomer(@Param("customerId") Customer customer);`
```

But I don't like to write custom queries like above. So I am planning to write converter to convert id(any primary key) into entity(expected source entityType). This converter should be applied globally, so that I can able to apply this logic all over my applications.

Any idea?

**UPDATE**

Spring throws the following error

```
   {
  "timestamp": 1475821684405,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.springframework.data.repository.support.QueryMethodParameterConversionException",
  "message": "Failed to convert 53 into com.order.model.Customer!",
  "path": "/orders/search/findByCustomer"
}
```

Comment: That is already done for you. Spring Data already has a converter for that.

Comment: No spring is not converting Id to entity as expected. I updated the error in question

Comment: Nonetheless it provides a converter already which you can use. The `DomainClassPropertyEditor` and/or `DomainClassConverter`. So you don't need to implement your own. Next to that a method like `findByCustomerId(@Param("customerId") long customer)` would also work.

Comment: Thank you @Deinum. After changing findByCustomer to findByCustomerId, the query worked fine without converter. spring-data-rest is great.

Comment: Well it should do the conversion. Have you added the `@EnableSpringDataWebSupport` on your configuration? This will register the convert. But the question remains do you really need the first query for a customer, to get the orders or is the id enough? Saves you a query and is theoretically faster.

Comment: I didn't added this annotaion EnableSpringDataWebSupport. I am writing a REST API so id is enough for me, which can be passed as a query param in API call.

Comment: Well it doesn't do much but it adds the converter to convert from id -> entity. Which would make your first code work.

Comment: I wonder is Spring able to resolve in such the way more complex dto structures with collections of ids that may contain other ids instead of objects? And is this the right place to do this conversion in controller at all?